# How do I "print" to a PostScript file from LibreOffice Write?

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, postscript

Using OpenOffice with 10.04 I was able to print to a Postscript file, but I find I can't do this with LibreOffice and 12.04 - print-to-file goes to PDF.

I want this feature so that I can use a FinePrint-like tool called fprint to print .PS files in booklet form.

When I print from other applications I'm offered the usual choice of printers, including print to .PS, but LibreOffice restricts my choice.

Comment: It's gone. You can see my post here http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=57250 The first link gives a possible workaround setting your printer using /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/spadmin

Answer (score 1):

I eventually came cross the solution by accident, but it is also dealt with at the URL given by nomnex (was above, now below!).

File=>Print: Select PDF
Choose Options Tab: Select Print To File 
Press "Print To File" button, select the destination directory, and enter the filename. It seems that the only option here is to print to .PS format.